# Weighted Clustering of pixels

Tags: python, clustering

I am working on a project in which I am working with depth images that are converted from point clouds. I have bounding boxes (bboxes) drawn in the depth image over objects. Therefore, I know where the object in the depth image lies. So say, for example, I have one bounding box in my depth image. I have extracted the pixels which lie inside this bounding box and then I also have respective depth value for each pixel inside the bounding box.

I want to do some weighted clustering using K Means. So, I want to select an area near the center of the rectangle and assign more weights to those pixels and then perform K_means so that I get centroids close to the center of the rectangles (bounding boxes). Because I have nan values in my depth array, I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35611465/python-scikit-learn-clustering-with-missing-data) version of K-Means which deals with the nan values. Though the results are good, I want to see if the results improve by adding weight to the pixels near the center.

So my question really is how do I assign weights to those (near the center of the bounding box) pixels (I can get the coordinates of those pixels inside the bounding box by simple math) and then fit and predict?

Also, Is there any better algorithm to do such a task?